Sphinx Manual Stemming fails for 's' Plurals
I turned off stemmming since it adds unexpected results and have been making my own library. This works:
regexp_filter=(?i)\b(Process|Switch|Business)\b=>\1es

as does
regexp_filter=(?i)\b(Plan)\b=>\1ning

In other words a search on Business or Businesses finds the same results as does Plan or Planning.
However single s plurals fails:
regexp_filter=(?i)\b(Dog|Word)\b=>\1s

As only Dogs or Words is found while Dog and Word find nothing. If I reverse the process to:
regexp_filter=(?i)\b(Dog|Word)s\b=>\1

Now it only finds Dog or Word but not Dogs or Words.
So every other suffix modification works for both forms but for some reason the added/removed 's' only finds the modified term.
Here is an interesting edit/solution/clue:
I just tested one of the words ALONE e.g
regexp_filter=\bDog\b=>Dogs

And the reciprocal searching works. Not sure it is the single character or the 's' itself but for the plurals looks like now, barring a solution to my original construction I need to individually map these.
